# How I can visualize correctly input form and datepicker in table cells?

Tags: nuxt.js

[image]I'm trying to build a table when the values are insert throught input form (there is also a datepicker form) but when i render my page I visualize the forms out of the cells, totally in a broken up way,
how can insert it correctly?

```
 <table v-if="invoice_customers.length > 0">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Expire Date</th>
        <th>Note</th>
      </tr>
      <tr
        v-for="invoice_customer in invoice_customers"
        :key="invoice_customer.id"
      >
        <td>
          <input
            type="number"
            name=""
            id=""
            v-model="invoice_customers.amount"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <b-form-datepicker
            v-model="invoice_customers.expire_date"
          ></b-form-datepicker>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" v-model="invoice_customers.note" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is the shape of your data? What is wrong and what do you expect? Did you inspected your Vue devtools?

Comment: Also, any updates on your latest questions? Some of them are still open.

Comment: All other question are solved, thank you for help now I''l close it

Comment: I've added a pic of my table, obv I want that every form will be down own column